# Calling Controller Action in src of <img>

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, image

In my cshtml page I have `<img src="/controllerName/actionName" />` and that works perfectly while I am testing.. but once I publish the `img` is broken.  How can I keep the image when I publish? My action that I am calling in the src of the image returns `return File(key.ToWebImage().GetBytes(), "image/jpeg");`

Is there another way so that when I publish, the image sticks?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.  All I needed was:

```
<img src='@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName") />
```